# How to configure axis2 POJOs for HTTPS transport?

Tags: https, apache-axis, pojo

I'm getting the following error for an axis2 POJO after the server was set up with a SHA-2 certificate:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: https is forbidden
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.preprocessRequest(AxisServlet.java:637)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:247)
```

My service is a POJO so there is no axis2.xml to configure the HTTPS transport.  Is there some other way to configure axis2 to allow HTTPS?

The service works fine with HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing something like what I pasted below on your axis2.xml

```
 <transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
   <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```